# SharePoint multiple list view depending on pemission for user

Tags: permissions, list-view, groups

Is there a possibility way to make a permission to list view depending on user

- groupa can see view1 only
- groupb can see view2 only

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking no you cannot set permissions on a view. However you can simulate or work around this.

First of all, you could create some hidden views in CAML, then expose them through webpart pages held in a document library that had dataview web parts on them.

If you just want to "hide" views rather than actually prevent users from getting to them then you can have links to the views in content editor webparts which are audience targetted but if he user knew the URL they could still get to the other views. Plus the ribbon would still give them access.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box SharePoint does not support this. List views can either be made public or private but cannot be separated based on the user group.

For addressing this you can probably create a single webpart page in the pages library. Add the list on a webpart zone and apply target audience for group A on this webpart. You can create a view also *specific to group A*.

Add the same list once again to the webpart zone on this page and this time apply target audience for group B. You can create a view also *specific to group B*.

This way you can separate the views for the list based on the groups and they are managed through target audience in a single webpart page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it OOTB. But, you can make a web service call to find out if the user is in a particular group then hide the view using javascript.

See example http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/hide-menu-items-in-list-view-toolbar-and-views-in-view-selector/.